# Insert statement in loop

Tags: php, html, mysqli

So i let customers fill in a form. The form contains the following information:

`name,
weight, 
number of axles, 
number of bogies`

etc.

Once the form is filled in, it gets send to the database, placed in the table `train_information` ,  and looks like this:

[image: Form filled in]

Now, the number_of_axles is a FK and also fill is the table `axle` after a train is inserted. the table looks like this then:

[image: Example 2]

Now, what i have is:

```
<div id="distances">
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        $_POST['number_of_axles'];
                            if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
                            for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
                                echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' placeholder='Distance $i' id='field' name='distance[$i]'>" . "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </div>
```

This is after they submitted the form, and a other page shows up with the number of text fields based on the number of axles.
So for example: They entered 12 axles (See Images). They now get to see 12 text fields.
In those fields they need to add distances. When they press submit (Submit button is not there yet) i want the distances to be filled in the table `axle`. (See second image, where it says NULL now)

How do i do this???

Comment: get all the last insert id's make an array and send them with post

Comment: select it by your train id then fetch those values and translate them into the markup inside the form, don't forget to correspond each input to each axle id, then make the necessary update for those input after submission

Comment: Stack is sick, pass it on and tell them that the deal they THINK they got on 2400 baud modems, wasn't a deal after all.

Comment: Once you have your *axle_id*s make them part of your input name, such as `name='distance[$axle_id]'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the $_POST['distance'] that at this point will be an array, so build the insert query. But you also need pass the train_id.

```
$train_id = $_POST['train_id'];
$distances = $_POST['distance'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO axle VALUES ";

$values = array();

foreach ($distances as $axle => $distance) {
    $values = " (NULL, $train_id, $axle, $distance)";
}

$sql .= implode($values, ",");
$sql .= ';';
```

This is simple implementation to build the query can (and probably should) change do fit to work in PDO or other lib.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *axle_id* as part of the `input` *name* attribute: `name=distance[$axle_id]`. For example:

*axles.php*

```
<?php

// assuming db connection $conn available
// insert train info, makes mysqli_insert_id available
// form action="axles_update.php"

$result = mysqli_query($conn, // mysqli_insert_id is trusted
    "SELECT axle_id FROM axle WHERE train_id = " . mysqli_insert_id($conn));

$ii = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<td><input type='text' placeholder='Distance " . $ii+ . 
         "' id='field' name='distance[" . $row['axle_id'] . "]'></td>\n";
}

?>
```

*update_axles.php*

```
<?php

// assuming db connection $conn available

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE axle SET distance = ? WHERE axle_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $value, $key);

foreach ( $_POST['distance'] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( '' != $value ) { mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

?>
```

Lots of details and checks missing here, but it shows the basic concept.